# jQuery ValidationEngine function validation issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

Here is my form (it only contains the fields required for this exercise, there are actually 20 entry fields):

```
<form id="reg_form" action="/register_submit" method="post">
  <fieldset>
      <ul class="form-list">
        <li>
          <div style="width:500">
            <label for="Username" class="required">Username (5 characters minimum,<br />Only Letters, Numbers, '~', '%', '.', ':', '-' and '_' allowed)<em>*</em></label><br />
            <div class="input-box">
              <input type="text" name="Username" id="Username" value="{embed:Username}" title="Username" class="validate[required,minSize[5],custom[onlyLetNumSpec]] register_input" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="register-customer-password">
          <div style="width:500">
            <label for="Password" class="required">Password (5 characters minimum,<br />Only Letters, Numbers, '~', '%', '.', ':', '-' and '_' allowed)<em>*</em></label><br />
            <div class="input-box">
              <input type="Password" name="Password" id="Password" title="Password" class="validate[required,minSize[5],custom[onlyLetNumSpec]] register_input" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <br />
          <div style="width:500">
            <label for="confirm_password" class="required">Confirm Password<em>*</em></label>
            <div class="input-box">
              <input type="password" name="confirm_password" title="Confirm Password" id="confirm_password" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetNumSpec],equals[Password],funcCall[checkUserPass]] register_input" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="button-set">
        <button class="button button-login" title="Create Account" type="submit">
          <span>
            <span>Create Account</span>
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Now, this is the function checkUserPass that is called on the validation after the confirm_password form field is filled and exited:

```
function checkUserPass(field, rules, i, options){
  $.ajax({type:'POST',
          url: '/json_api/ParticipantSelectByUser/', 
          data: {"Username":$("#Username").val(), "Password":$("#Password").val()},
          dataType: 'json', 
          success: checkUserPassResult,
          error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
              alert(xhr.status);
              alert(thrownError);
          } // error
  });
}

function checkUserPassResult(data) {
  if(data.result.ParticipantID > 0) {
    /*--- There is already a user with this combination ---*/
    return options.allrules.checkUserPass.alertText;
  } // if(data.result)
}
```

I *KNOW* that there is a data.result returned and as such, there is already a user with that user/pwd combination.

However, there is never a validation message shown. I believe I have followed the correct way to do validation with a function call. I cannot use an ajax validation rule because of the need to pass both username and password to the ajax call. What seems to be the problem here? All my other validations on this form work just fine.

Here are the custom rules required for the above validations:

```
"onlyLetNumSpec": {
    // Good for database fields
    "regex": /^[0-9a-zA-Z_-~%.:]+$/,
    "alertText": "* Only Letters, Numbers, tilde(~), pct(%), period(.), colon(:), hyphen(-) and underscore(_) allowed"
},
"checkUserPass": {
  "alertText": "* A User with the same Username and/or Password has been detected. Please change one of the entries."
}
```

Edit Note; I have updated the checkUserPass function to call another funstion in success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using async ajax, so your return value is returned nowhere. You will have to call a function with your data. And you will have to prevent the submit with e.preventDefault() (!!!) outside the ajax function.

```
if(data.result) {
    function_to_validate_the_data(data.result);
} // if(data.result)
```

Comment: But the data variable in the success function DOES have data.

Comment: The function call demo did not say to return true or false, just the alertText.

Comment: The ajax call is async. This function will not return anything, because it calls ajax and nothing else. You will have to return false outside the ajax call and work with the data in a new function. Maybe this link will help to understand http://arshadinfo.wordpress.com/2008/05/25/what-is-the-difference-between-asynchronous-ajax-and-synchronous-request/

Comment: Maybe you aren't following me. in the success call, there IS a result and it does have values.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your example, but as I see you want to return options.allrules.checkUserPass.alertText. But you cannot return anything in an asynchronous call, because the call is detached from the function. That means the function will not wait for an answer.

Comment: Even when I update the function to do what you are saying (see above edit), it still doesn't show the message.

Comment: Maybe that is why they gave the ajax call methods. let me check those out next.

Comment: Could you please post your event handler? $("form").on("submit", ...)

Comment: It does nothing but concatenate a phone number.

Comment: Ok, I will try to explain again. You will need to call $(form).on("submit", function() {}). In this submit, you will have to submit your ajax call or call the function above and return false and/or preventDefault to the form, so it is NOT submited. Then you will have to wait for an answer and call a function with your returned dataset or if there is no dataset submit the form with $(form).submit(). You can see this in the source of http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/ajax-validation.php

Comment: I am doing inline validation, not on submission. Besides, I modified to using the ajax methods and am getting somewhere.

Comment: It's quiet the same for onkeyup, etc.

Comment: Finally go it working using the ajax methods, thanks for leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found the solution! All you have to do is return from main function not the call back.

```
function checkUserPass(field, rules, i, options){
var ret = "";
$.ajax({type:'POST',
  url: '/json_api/ParticipantSelectByUser/', 
  data: {"Username":$("#Username").val(), "Password":$("#Password").val()},
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false, 
  success: function(response)
  {
     if(data.result.ParticipantID > 0) 
      {
          ret = "There is already a user with this combination";
      } 

  },
  error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      alert(xhr.status);
      alert(thrownError);
  } // error
});

 **return ret;**
}
```

Comment: That will return an empty string most times (unless the ajax response arrives extremely fast, probably only on localhost...)

Comment: @bfavaretto,  you are right. I  tried this after deployment and had to make a change to make the ajax call synchronous.